# zsh command cannot found aws2-wrap

Tags: python, macos

I'm trying to run [aws2-wrap](https://github.com/linaro-its/aws2-wrap#run-a-command-using-aws-sso-credentials) in my macos.

I did

```
python3 -m pip install aws2-wrap
DEPRECATION: Configuring installation scheme with distutils config files is deprecated and will no longer work in the near future. If you are using a Homebrew or Linuxbrew Python, please see discussion at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/76621
Requirement already satisfied: aws2-wrap in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (1.2.2)
```

But when I do a

```
aws2-wrap
zsh: command not found: aws2-wrap
```

This is my path

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/dturcios/Go/bin:/usr/local/opt/go/libexec/bin
```

Comment: I'd search the entire file system for it using  `find / -name aws2-wrap`. It must be installed somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

you need to export the .local/bin

```
export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH
```